# Режим смешивания полупрозрачной текстуры и полупрозрачного буфера

Tags: opengl, directx, monogame, blend

### Дано:

Monogame (XNA). Но думаю всё это относится и к любым графическим движкам.

Имеется прозрачный бэкбуфер, то есть с цветом фона rgba( 0, 0, 0, 0 ). Как можно сразу заметить, у этого прозрачного цвета чёрный цвет и полная прозрачность.

Также имеется полупрозрачная текстура, которая отрисовывается на данном бэкбуфере. Например она с цветом rgba( 255, 255, 255, 128 ). То есть белая текстура с половинной прозрачностью.

### Ожидается:

Что в результате смешения будет изображение исходной текстуры, как-будто её ни с чем не смешивали. Потому что буфер прозрачный. Картинка + прозрачный цвет = картинка.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Проблема:

Смешивание учитывает цвет бэкбуфера, то есть чёрный, и наполовину подмешивает его в результат.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Попытки решения:

Вот пример настройки смешивания в monogame на C#:

```
new BlendState(){
    ColorSourceBlend = Blend.SourceAlpha, // 1)
    AlphaSourceBlend = Blend.One, // 2)
    ColorDestinationBlend = Blend.InverseSourceAlpha, // 3)
    AlphaDestinationBlend = Blend.One, // 4)
    ColorBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add, // 5)
    AlphaBlendFunction = BlendFunction.Add, // 6)
};
```

Разберу построчно что здесь описано:

1. Вклад текстуры в результат равен альфаканалу текстуры;
2. Альфаканал текстуры не меняется (будет 128 = 0.5);
3. Вклад буфера в результат равен формуле ( 1 - альфаканал текстуры );
4. Альфаканал буфера не меняется (будет 0);
5. Результирующий цвет (RGB) равен сумме вкладов с пунктов 1 и 3.
6. Результирующая прозрачность (A) равна сумме прозрачностей с пунктов 2 и 4.

Что здесь не так:

Всё хорошо, кроме третьего пункта. Как видно, в нём вклад цвета буфера в результирующий цвет равен ( 1 - альфаканал текстуры ). Это было бы верно, если бы у буфера не было прозрачности. То есть его цвет вносил бы свои 50% в результат, и мы бы видели смешивание цветов. Это хорошо работает если на этом буфере уже было что-то нарисовано. Тогда две текстуры хорошо смешиваются (и эта возможность должна сохраниться).

Я не могу найти такой настройки смешивания, которая говорила бы формулу:
Вклад буфера в результат равен = ( 1 - альфаканал текстуры ) * альфаканал буфера. Или что-то вроде того. Чтобы прозрачность буфера учитывалась и его чёрный цвет не мешал.

Но "слои" подобного рода нормально смешиваются во всех графических программах и браузерах. Соответственно можно оптимистично предположить, что это что-то тривиальное.

### Вопрос:

Какую настройку смешивания применить или куда копать?

Думаю подойдёт ответ не только для C# и monogame, потому что эти смешивания универсальны.

Answer (score 0):

Выяснил, что это "общеизвестная" ситуация с блендингом.

Для её решения требуется BlendState.AlphaBlend и PremultiplyAlpha: True. Что меняет принцип кодирования и работы текстур. Их значения RGB тогда умножаются на альфаканал и так хранятся.

Поэтому сразу рассматриваются как вносящие вклад в результат, а не являются исходными значениями как привычно для нормальных людей. И тогда их можно смешать, потому что смешиваются вклады в результат без необходимости умножать на их альфаканал.

Такой вот костыльный способ вместо отсутствующего для этой ситуации режима смешивания в видеокартах.

Comment: Объяснение схожей ситуации - https://shawnhargreaves.com/blog/premultiplied-alpha-and-image-composition.html

Comment: Здесь описано что это повсеместно используется в Win2D - https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI3/html/PremultipliedAlpha.htm